# Confusing memcpy behaviour, how to stop overlapping

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, char, memcpy

I have the following class:

```
BridgingPacketHeader header;
uint32_t ownedByReceiver;
uint32_t nameLength;
uint32_t idLength;
uint32_t uriLength;
char* id;
char* name;
char* uri;
```

BridgingPacketHeader is a class of 5 uint32_t values and so its size is 20 bytes.
I am attempting to correctly fill in the length information and copy some information into id,name and uri using memcpy, however whilst debugging, the behaviour is odd. Name and uri values overlap.

Code:

```
                //SubCcuPacket *subCcuPk = nullptr;
            uint32_t packet_size = (uint32_t) sizeof(SubCcuPacket);
            //Ensuring the total packet size is correct
            uint32_t idLength = (uint32_t)(std::strlen(subCcu1.second.id) + 1);
            packet_size += idLength;
            uint32_t uriLength = (uint32_t)(std::strlen(subCcu1.second.uri) + 1);
            packet_size += uriLength;
            uint32_t nameLength = (uint32_t)(std::strlen(subCcu1.second.name) + 1);
            packet_size += nameLength;

            SubCcuPacket * subCcuPk = (SubCcuPacket*)malloc(packet_size);
            if (sentUri == subCcu1.second.uri) {
                subCcuPk->ownedByReceiver = 1; //if equal uri
            }
            else {
                subCcuPk->ownedByReceiver = 0; //if sub ccu is not same as reciever
            }       
            
            subCcuPk->idLength = idLength;
            memcpy(&subCcuPk->id, subCcu1.second.id, idLength);

            subCcuPk->nameLength = nameLength;
            memcpy(&subCcuPk->name, subCcu1.second.name, nameLength);

            subCcuPk->uriLength = uriLength;
            memcpy(&subCcuPk->uri, subCcu1.second.uri, uriLength);

            s->send_packet((uint8_t *)subCcuPk, packet_size);
```

Below are screenshots of the behaviour in memory after each memcpy, using information:

```
subCcu1.second.uri = 10.92.84.162
subCcu1.second.name = bridgex1
subCcu1.second.id = 1
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, as the program went, the third memcpy overlapped the name in memory, any clues as to what may be causing this? I have heard something about character pointers and 4 bytes which may be why bridgex1 is cut off after 4 bytes but I am not sure as to how to solve this.

Comment: id, name and uri are pointers to memory. You are copying to your pointer, which may be 4 or 8 byte (depending on 32bit or 64bit compilation). Please read up on pointers in general.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` instead of raw pointers?

Comment: What you should do is allocate memory to your pointers as long as needed (so .name = new char[length]), and then memcpy to .name, and not to &.name. Or you could change it to char name[20], and can then memcpy up to 20 characters there.

Comment: The data is to be sent through a packet, this packet is formatted from the structure to be sent ::
s->send_packet((uint8_t *)subCcuPk, packet_size);

Comment: Are you really coding in C++, or in C? Looks like C to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a struct like

```
struct packet {
    BridgingPacketHeader header;
    uint32_t ownedByReceiver;
    uint32_t nameLength;
    uint32_t idLength;
    uint32_t uriLength;
    char* id;
    char* name;
    char* uri;
};
```

the id, name and uri are pointer to memory in buffer. If you want to serialize it, you basically would have to manually add them together, and keep track of the size of your memory chunks.

Easier would be to do

```
struct packet {
    BridgingPacketHeader header;
    uint32_t ownedByReceiver;
    uint32_t nameLength;
    uint32_t idLength;
    uint32_t uriLength;
    char id[20];
    char name[20];
    char uri[20];
};
```

because then the sizeof actually works, and each parameter can hold up to 19 characters (plus null terminator).